# Replacing the background of the main menu in minecraft

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, minecraft

I have gotten my code for this mostly working using some code i found for drawing with quads but it seems to only take up the lower left-hand corner of the minecraft screen with my image when it should take up the whole thing.
I think i need some way to scale it but i don't know why i should need that or if i do...
the code for doing the drawing is correct it's just that it's not drawing in the right spot... and i don't know why.

```
private void drawImageQuad(int textureHandle, int x, int y, float w, float h) {
    // activate the specified texture
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D,textureHandle);
    // prepare to render in 2D
    setOrthoOn();
    // draw the image textured onto a quad
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f);
    GL11.glVertex3f( (float)x, (float)y, (float)0);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1f, 0f);
    GL11.glVertex3f( (float)x+w, (float)y, (float)0);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1f, 1f);
    GL11.glVertex3f( (float)x+w, (float)y+h, (float)0);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0f, 1f);
    GL11.glVertex3f( (float)x, (float)y+h, (float)0);
    GL11.glEnd();
    // restore the previous perspective and model views
    setOrthoOff();
}


private void setOrthoOn()
{
    // prepare to render in 2D
    if(GL11.glIsEnabled(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST)){
        depthTest=true;
        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    }

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glPushMatrix();                            // preserve perspective view
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();                          // clear the perspective matrix
    GL11.glOrtho(0,width,0,height,-1,1);  // turn on 2D
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glPushMatrix();     // Preserve the Modelview Matrix
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();   // clear the Modelview Matrix
}

private void setOrthoOff()
{
    // restore the original positions and views
    if(depthTest){
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        depthTest = false;
    }
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
}

/**
 * Draws the screen and all the components in it.
 */
public void drawScreen(int par1, int par2, float par3)
{
    //renderSkybox(par1, par2, par3);
    Tessellator tessellator = Tessellator.instance;
    double zoom = width/(double)384;
    int widthOffset = (int)((width - (384*zoom))/2);
    int widthOffset2 = widthOffset +(width*(384/256));
    this.drawImageQuad(mc.renderEngine.getTexture("/title/background0.png"),widthOffset,(height - (int)(256*zoom))/2,widthOffset+(int)(256*zoom),height+((height - (int)(256*zoom))/2));
    this.drawImageQuad(mc.renderEngine.getTexture("/title/background1.png"),widthOffset2,(height - (int)(256*zoom))/2,widthOffset2+(int)(256*zoom),height+((height - (int)(256*zoom))/2));
```

Comment: You want to draw a single full-screen quad? Or two? What is `width` and `height` in `drawScreen`? In `setOrthoOn()`, the code uses a variable named `mc`. _`depthTest` is false when it is enabled_?!

Comment: no im trying to draw a fullscreen image that is split into two images. depthTest variable just tells it to turn on the depth test after it is if  and only if it was on when it started to draw.

Comment: Is all that coordinate transforming _really_ necessary? What prohibits using `width` and `height` directly for the `drawImageQuad` calls? After all, the code uses an orthographic projection...

Comment: the fact that the image is broken up into two images one of them is 256px by 256px and the other is 128px by 256px